# Python os.system not returning the same data as command prompt

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to write a script that will use netstat to check ephemeral ports on a windows machine.  When I test this script in the IDLE on Windows, it returns with a 0.

Here is my code that I'm testing:

```
import os
oPorts=os.system('netstat -ano | find /i \"estab\" /c')
print(oPorts)
```

Here is what happens when I try to run that in Python:

[image: os.system Python Script]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjCHw.png)

Here's the output however when I run the same thing in command prompt.

[image: cmd prompt output]

So why is Python outputting a 0 when there are clearly about 311 established connections on the Windows host?  What am I missing?

Comment: As I mentioned, it's on a windows machine and grep is not an option.

Comment: My bad. .. subprocess is best bet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) function returns the exit status of the command.Not the output of the command. You should be using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) module instead. Then you can capture the output.

Comment: Okay so here's my new code: `proc = subprocess.check_output('netstat -ano | find /i \"estab\" /c',
                               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                               shell=True)` . This actually does return the correct number but there is also jargon before and after it.  Instead of just returning "330" for example it returns "b'330\r\n" . How do I get rid of that other junk and just have it return an integer?

Comment: @RaptorPete On the returned bytes object do: `oPorts = oProts.decode("ascii").strip()`.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from an executable process is **not** the same as its output. By convention a process returns 0 to indicate success and anything else to indicate failure. When you run a command from the command line, thbe return value is not typically printed. To capture the output, you need to redirect `stdout`.

Comment: If you see below under Keith's response I was able to change up my code and get a number output.  But now it's also including some other random characters. Any idea how I can change the output of b'330\r\n to just say "330"?
Thanks

Comment: @RaptorPete The notation `b''` is python's way of telling you that this is binary data. You can call `decode()` on it (with the correct encoding name) to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gave me exactly the output I was intending.

```
import subprocess

established = (subprocess.Popen('netstat -ano | find /i \"estab\" /c',
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               shell=True).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip())
```

I'm not sure the difference exactly between `check_output` and `Popen`, but `Popen` and `.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip())` were the keys.

Comment: `Popen` is the class that implements the core features. `call`, `check_call`, and `check_output` are convenience functions that wrap `Popen`. Recent versions of Python 3 also have a more generic `run` convenience function. They've also added `encoding` and `errors` parameters for all these functions.